# How can i use colorWithPatternImage in Xcode?

Tags: image, xcode4, design-patterns, draw

I've this code:

```
brushColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Instead to insert a "greenColor" i'd like to insert a patternImage like:

```
brushColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage(UIImage *)];
```

in "`(UIImage *)`" section i've insert `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]`;

When i go build and run my application, my brush haven't any color, and alpha.
what can i do? Where i've commit any mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I have this setup for my view and it works fine:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myBackgroundImage.png"]];
```